# How to give properties to a .csv file in Java

Tags: java, excel, csv

I am having trouble implementing properties to a .csv file when I export it through Java. I will mainly be using the .csv in Excel. Is it possible to give bold text or any sort of properties to a .csv file in Java? Specifically, I want to give a background color to certain cells and make some text bold to differentiate the cells from other cells. For example, I want to make the first row in the .csv file bold to show that the first row is like a header.

One restraint, I want to avoid using any API's from the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want bold or other features to show up in Excel you need to create an excel file.  csv means Comma delimited file.  All it has is data separated by commas.  No formatting what-so-ever.

Comment: Sorry for the bad news.  Feel free to upvote/accept the answer!  :)